# How to rotate a certain number of words in java

Tags: java, string, input, reverse, words

I need to create a program that moves words in a string that is inputted by the user. The user will enter a sentence and enter the number of words they want to move. If the user entered "I have a dog named Spot" then entered 2, the output would be "named Spot I have a dog". I am not really sure how to go about this. I have code written to reverse the order of a string that I just wrote but I am not sure if that applies here. Also it does not even work. I cannot figure out how to make it work.

I rewrote some of my code. I now have this. But it says there is an input mismatch.

Comment: this is where modular arithmetic can be useful. Understand what the `%` does and it will simplify the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, reversing the string won't help you. I would suggest using [tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) to split your string on spaces, then build your string based on this array.

```
get input string and number of words to be moved from user
tokenize input string on spaces

if number of tokens is greater than number of words to be moved then
   build a new string starting with the number of words needed from the end of the tokens
   add the rest of the tokens from the beginning of the tokens
endif
```

Your existing code is very nearly this, you already tokenize the input string, but you then build it backwards which is much more work than you need to do. You can just grab the number of words you need from the end of the tokens array and then start build a string like that.

I'd give you code for this, but I suspect it's a school project and that wouldn't help educate you.

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a string probably isn't relevant here. But I recommend trying *something* before posting here.

One idea might be to split the words into a list/array and try to rotate each element of the list. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus for rotation:

```
String s = "I have a dog named Spot";
String[] words = s.split(" ");

int ROT = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    System.out.print(words[(i + words.length - ROT)%words.length] + " ");
```

**OUTPUT:** named Spot I have a dog

Comment: I tried to input this into my code but there seems to be an error and I am not sure why.

Comment: Can you explain more? The code above runs by itself, so I need to know  more about your code to understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer.
However, if this is homework of algorithm, you shuold think by yourself.

I only suggest an example using java built-in class.

```
String str = "Please think of other answer if this is homework";
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(" ")));
Collections.rotate(list, 3);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(String s:list){
    sb.append(s).append(" ");
}
System.out.println(sb);//"this is homework Please think of other answer if "
```

Comment: I was thinking of
`Collections.shuffle();`

Comment: Hi Aneel, I chose "rotate" because I understood the asker wrote "move words according to the number entered".

Comment: Make sense. By the way, since this question seems like an assignment, we should be using these built in functions to do the real work.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to the opinion that we can/should use such built-in function for the real work. But for assignment, we shuold not, I think. Because "rotating array" is good theme for thinking algorithm deeply. Built-in functions wrap the algorithm, so they are not proper.